# Ubuntu SDK HTML5 App scan dir

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I am making a small HTML5 app because I didn't get into QML yet *(and can reuse some foreign code)* and I am trying to load a bunch of files from a directory, possibly outside the app dir, but e.g. in `~/Documents/`. But to request them I first have to get a list of the contents of that dir.

How can I get this information into my JavaScript scope?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read the manual correctly (https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/html-5/guides/html5-guide/), you can use Web APIs.

This means you can use the <input type="file" multiple> element in your HTML. The handling of the file should be done in javascript, see https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/file/File

Full example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="yourFileID" multiple>
<script>
    document.getElementById('yourFileID').addEventListener('change', handleFileImport, false);

    function handleFileImport(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;

        fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        }

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```